# Erro ao acessar o RStudio 127.0.0.1

Tags: mongodb, conexão, r, localhost

Estou tentando acessar o RStudio e aparece este erro:

> 127.0.0.1 recusou estabelecer ligação.
> Experimente:
>
> Verificar a ligação
> Verificar o proxy e a firewall
> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

se eu for no cmd e der ping:

C:\Windows\system32> `ping 127.0.0.1`

Obtenho a resposta:

> Disparando 127.0.0.1 com 32 bytes de dados: Resposta de 127.0.0.1:
> bytes=32 tempo<1ms TTL=128 Resposta de 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 tempo<1ms
> TTL=128 Resposta de 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 tempo<1ms TTL=128 Resposta de
> 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 tempo<1ms TTL=128
>
> Estatísticas do Ping para 127.0.0.1:
> Pacotes: Enviados = 4, Recebidos = 4, Perdidos = 0 (0% de
> perda), Aproximar um número redondo de vezes em milissegundos:
> Mínimo = 0ms, Máximo = 0ms, Média = 0ms

==========================================================================

Digitando no `cmd` mongo, ocorre:

> MongoDB shell version v4.2.0 connecting to:
> mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
> 2020-01-28T20:00:33.327-0300 E  QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect
> to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException:
> Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Nenhuma conex�o
> p�de ser feita porque a m�quina de destino as recusou ativamente. :
> connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17 @(connect):2:6
> 2020-01-28T20:00:33.330-0300 F  -        [main] exception: connect
> failed 2020-01-28T20:00:33.330-0300 E  -        [main] exiting with
> code 1

==========================================================================

Como faço para corrigir isto? Será que meu localhost é outro ? Ou o que pode ser?

Comment: Você conferiu se a sua versão é compatível com os requerimentos ou fez [reset](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-Desktop-s-State) do Rstudio state?

Comment: Por acaso vc está com o mongo em um container?

Comment: Não fiz reset. É bom fazer o reset ou não fazer o reset ? Sem conteiner. Eu instalei para estudar, não estudei ainda, não usei. Aí fui instalar o Rstudio. Deu erro. Lembrei que o mongo usava localhost tbm, testei lá para ver oq dava, deu o contexto acima.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver? Fiz os resets aqui, mas ainda não abre.

Comment: Eu fiz o reset e nada. Aí formatei o pc. Deu certo.